# SQLite: Selecting values from two columns as if they were stored in one column

Tags: sqlite

Using SQLite, how can I select values from two columns into one result set, as if the came from only one column? I have a table like this:

```
 value_1 | value_2
---------+---------
 a       | a
 b       | b
 c       | c
 a       | d
```

Now if I do

```
SELECT value_1, COUNT(value_1) AS count_value_1
FROM some_table
GROUP BY value_1
ORDER BY count_value_1 DESC
```

I get something like this:

```
a | 2
b | 1
c | 1
```

And what I would like to do is to also include all values from the second column (as if they were also stored in the first one), so that I get:

```
a | 3
b | 2
c | 2
d | 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With UNION ALL:

```
select t.value, count(*) from (
  select value_1 value from some_table
  union all
  select value_2 from some_table
) t
group by t.value
```

If there are `null` values and you do not want them to be counted then add this condition:

```
where t.value is not null
```

before the `group by` clause.

Comment: That's it :-) Thanks a lot!